# Handling dimension with empty names in icCube

Tags: iccube

How can I get icCube to handle a dimension where there are empty values in the backing table? I get the following error message from icCube when I try to scan our tables:

Data table 'public.accounting_area_dim', line '22' : The member key:'22' has no name (nameColumn:area) (level:[Area].[Area].[Area])

This is absolutely correct, there are empty strings in the dimension table - I'd like to treat it as "Unknown" or something similar, is this possible in icCube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the empty string into something else within the table definition as following:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I found this out but this is the correct answer - accepted.